# What happens when payable function fails a `require` test? Will the contract refund the user?

Tags: solidity

What happens when payable function fails a `require` test?
Will the contract refund the user? (I am not asking about gas fees)

```
function deposit(uint age) payable {
 require(age >= 18, "Sorry you should be 18+ to deposit");
 logs[msg.sender] = msg.value;
}
```

Comment: if age is less than 18 will the ether sent with the call be refunded? or should i manually refund it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assert vs. require within Solidity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847407/assert-vs-require-within-solidity)

Comment: @Yilmaz no, if someone sends ether (other than the gas fee) will the ether received in msg.value be refunded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transaction will be reverted and users funds will be refunded